# Missing Keyword (ORA-00905) - Erreur SQL : ORA-00905

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00905

I have the below statement which is returning the aforementioned 905 error. Any ideas?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW SYNT_CE CACHE USING INDEX REFRESH ON DEMAND FORCE USING DEFAULT ROLLBACK SEGMENT DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
WITH SYNT_AV AS (SELECT CIRC_BV, CASE WHEN SUM(C_AVANCEMENT) > 1 THEN 'non transmis' WHEN SUM(C_AVANCEMENT) = 1 THEN 'tï¿½lï¿½phonï¿½' ELSE 'confirmï¿½' END AS C_AVANCEMENT
FROM (SELECT SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV, (CASE SYNT_BV.C_AVANCEMENT WHEN 'non transmis' THEN 2 WHEN 'tï¿½lï¿½phonï¿½' THEN 1 WHEN 'confirmï¿½' THEN 0 END) AS C_AVANCEMENT
FROM SYNT_BV GROUP BY SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV, (CASE SYNT_BV.C_AVANCEMENT WHEN 'non transmis' THEN 2 WHEN 'tï¿½lï¿½phonï¿½' THEN 1 WHEN 'confirmï¿½' THEN 0 END)) AV GROUP BY CIRC_BV)
SELECT TO_NUMBER(SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV) AS C_CE, SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV, SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV, SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV || case WHEN SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV = '01' then 'er Ardt' WHEN SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV <> '01' then 'Ã¨me Ardt'  as L_CIRC_BV, SYNT_BV.NUMERO_TOUR, SYNT_BV.NUMERO_TOUR, SYNT_BV.DATE_TOUR, SYNT_BV.TYPE_ELECTION, SYNT_BV.LIBELLE_ELECTION,
      SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_INSCRIT)        AS NB_INSCRIT,
      SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_VOTANT)         AS NB_VOTANT,
      SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_EMARGEMENT)     AS NB_EMARGEMENT,
      SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_PROCURATION)    AS NB_PROCURATION,
      SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_EXPRIME)        AS NB_EXPRIME,
      SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_VOTE_BLANC)     AS NB_VOTE_BLANC,
      SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_VOTE_NUL)       AS NB_VOTE_NUL,
      SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_VOTE_B_NUL)     AS NB_VOTE_B_NUL,
      SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_VOTE_B_NUL_ABS) AS NB_VOTE_B_NUL_ABS,
    [...]
    ORDER BY SYNT_BV.ARR_BV;

    CREATE INDEX SYNT_AR_INDEX_C_CAINSEE ON SYNT_AR (C_CAINSEE ASC);
```

Comment: You seem to have a `select` with no `from` or `group by`.  Makes it a bit hard to figure out the problem.  I would suggest simplify, simplify, simplify until you isolate the error and fix it.

Comment: Syntax errors are easier to spot when the code is laid out properly, and in mixed case. The fact that your lines are so long we need to use the scroll bars makes it very hard for us to spot what bloomers you might have made. Readability is a feature your code should have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW SYNT_CE CACHE USING INDEX REFRESH ON DEMAND FORCE USING     DEFAULT ROLLBACK SEGMENT DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
WITH SYNT_AV AS (SELECT CIRC_BV, CASE WHEN SUM(C_AVANCEMENT) > 1 THEN 'non transmis'     WHEN SUM(C_AVANCEMENT) = 1 THEN 'tï¿½lï¿½phonï¿½' ELSE 'confirmï¿½' END AS C_AVANCEMENT
FROM (SELECT SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV, (CASE SYNT_BV.C_AVANCEMENT WHEN 'non transmis' THEN 2     WHEN 'tï¿½lï¿½phonï¿½' THEN 1 WHEN 'confirmï¿½' THEN 0 END) AS C_AVANCEMENT
FROM SYNT_BV GROUP BY SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV, (CASE SYNT_BV.C_AVANCEMENT WHEN 'non transmis' THEN 2 WHEN 'tï¿½lï¿½phonï¿½' THEN 1 WHEN 'confirmï¿½' THEN 0 END)) AV GROUP BY CIRC_BV)
SELECT TO_NUMBER(SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV) AS C_CE, SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV, SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV, SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV || case WHEN SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV = '01' then 'er Ardt' WHEN SYNT_BV.CIRC_BV <> '01' then 'Ã¨me Ardt' END as L_CIRC_BV, SYNT_BV.NUMERO_TOUR, SYNT_BV.NUMERO_TOUR, SYNT_BV.DATE_TOUR, SYNT_BV.TYPE_ELECTION, SYNT_BV.LIBELLE_ELECTION,
  SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_INSCRIT)        AS NB_INSCRIT,
  SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_VOTANT)         AS NB_VOTANT,
  SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_EMARGEMENT)     AS NB_EMARGEMENT,
  SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_PROCURATION)    AS NB_PROCURATION,
  SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_EXPRIME)        AS NB_EXPRIME,
  SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_VOTE_BLANC)     AS NB_VOTE_BLANC,
  SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_VOTE_NUL)       AS NB_VOTE_NUL,
  SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_VOTE_B_NUL)     AS NB_VOTE_B_NUL,
  SUM(SYNT_BV.NB_VOTE_B_NUL_ABS) AS NB_VOTE_B_NUL_ABS,
[...]
ORDER BY SYNT_BV.ARR_BV;

CREATE INDEX SYNT_AR_INDEX_C_CAINSEE ON SYNT_AR (C_CAINSEE ASC);
```

You have missed *END* word at the end of your CASE statement.